# How to check if a list of objects in a model of a view is empty using razor syntax in a HTML page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How should I check the model on a view if it has a list of objects that are not empty using razor syntax in an HTML page?

I need to stop the rendering of the partial view if that list is empty.

while testing and trying to set this up I tried this:

```
@if (Model.Wealth.WealthList != null)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("_Wealth", Model.Wealth)
                }
```

But this solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty collection is still a non-null collection, but with zero elements

Assuming `WealthList` is a collection, you can use the `Any` extension method

```
@if (Model.Wealth!=null && Model.Wealth.WealthList != null 
                                                && Model.Wealth.WealthList.Any())
{
    @Html.Partial("_Wealth", Model.Wealth)
}
```

The `Any()` method will return `true` if it has at least one item in the collection.

The `Any` extension method is defined in the `System.Linq` namespace which is in the `System.Core` assembly. Add a reference to it if not already added.

Comment: you must include `using System.Linq` to access `.Any()`

Comment: Any is an extension method defined in `System.Linq` namespace. You can use `@using System.Linq;` in your view if it is not already available

Comment: I'd also recommend setting your list inner models to an emplty list in the model constructor so that you can remove null checks from your code.

Comment: @EndritSheholli  Looking at shyju's edit, and all those null checks, it might be better to perform a RenderAction and have a child action that retrieves its own partial view and populates it instead of a deeply nested view to the main view.

Comment: Yea, I personally prefer less C# code in razor views. I believe collections should not be null at all. So the view model can have a constructor which initializes this property to an empty collection which will removes the ugly null checks in the view.